ros2 run works ok but ros2 launch gives "executable not found on the libexec directory" error
The package is iiwa_arm_controller and the executable is end_effector_joint_trajectory
The package builds and I can run it using ros2 run iiwa_arm_controller end_effector_joint_trajectory.py 
However, when I run ros2 launch iiwa_arm_controller iiwa_arm_controller.launch.py I get the error:
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executable 'end_effector_joint_trajectory' not found on the libexec directory '/home/russell/ros2_ws/install/iiwa_arm_controller/lib/iiwa_arm_controller'

Here is the output of ls -l /home/russell/ros2_ws/install/iiwa_arm_controller/lib/iiwa_arm_controller:
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 russell russell 98 Dec 19 14:41 end_effector_joint_trajectory.py -> /home/russell/ros2_ws/src/iiwa_arm_controller/iiwa_arm_controller/end_effector_joint_trajectory.py

I suspect the problem is the executable is being built with the *.py extention and ros2 launch doesn't expect this but I don't know how to resolve the problem. Here is the launch file:

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():

    arg1 = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'desired_x', default_value='0.0', description='Desired x position of end-effector'
    )
    arg2 = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'desired_y', default_value='0.0', description='Desired y position of end-effector'
    )
    arg3 = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'desired_z', default_value='0.0', description='Desired z position of end-effector'
    )

    position_goals = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare('iiwa_arm_controller'), 'config', 'trajectory_config.yaml']
    )

    desired_x = LaunchConfiguration('desired_x')
    desired_y = LaunchConfiguration('desired_y')
    desired_z = LaunchConfiguration('desired_z')

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            arg1, 
            arg2, 
            arg3,
            Node(
                package='iiwa_arm_controller',
                executable='end_effector_joint_trajectory',
                name='end_effector_joint_trajectory',
                parameters=[
                    position_goals, 
                    {'desired_x': desired_x, 'desired_y': desired_y, 'desired_z': desired_z}
                ],
                output="both",

            )
        ]
    )



I've seen this too and suspect it's a bug with the --symlink-install (or perhaps it's user error in both our cases). In any case, switching to a non-symlink install colcon build should address it for you
